# How to detect a space in a string in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to detect for a palindrome, and got stuck with the space. I was trying to detect for a space and if found increment to the next byte. but still not working, this is my code.

```
    loop:  ldrb    r5, [r1]
    ldrb    r6, [r3]
    cmp     r5,  #' '
    beq    skip
    cmp     r6, #' '
    beq     skip2

    cmp     r5, r6 
    bne     bad
    add     r1, r1, #1
    sub     r3, r3, #1
    cmp     r1, r3
    bne     loop

    skip:   add     r1, r1, #1
            b     loop

    skip2:  add     r3, r3, #1
            b     loop
```

Comment: Shouldn't one of the pointers (e.g. r3) be decremented in ***both*** (i.e. all) cases: that is, whether skipped (as in skip2) or not skipped?

Comment: Could you describe the task you are trying to implement? Use [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58229507/edit) link to edit your question.

Comment: asm style tip: left-justify your labels so they're visible.  Usually it's best to put labels on a separate line from instructions so you can still have your instructions only 1 indent level over from your labels and still have them line up.